# How do mixed models deal with a group whose response has zero mean and variance?

Tags: mixed-model, variance, zero-inflation

I have written a mixed model (following syntax in `R` package `lme4`) such as:

```
response ~ comp1 + comp2 + group + (1|sp)
```

- `response`, `comp1` and `comp2` are continuous.
- `group` and `sp` are categorical with 3 and 10 levels respectively.

But the distribution of `response` in each level of `group` is as follows:

```
         n      mean       var
group1  18 0.0000000 0.0000000
group2  33 0.5151818 0.1914605
group3  18 0.4510000 0.3125364
```

1. How do mixed models deal with such a situation?
2. Does `group1` work as an *attractor* biasing results?
3. Should I discard `group1` from the data used in the model?

Comment: The only way to have a sample variance of 0 is for all the 18 values to be the same and since the sample mean is 0 that value is 0.

Comment: I think you need to discuss how group1 has zero values for response. Do they represent a null set of some kind?

Comment: @MichaelChernick you are totally right, that is how my data looks. My doubt is: will mixed models (lme4 o lmerTest) crash?

Comment: @DJohnson `group1` is a set of observations that *had to be* zeros, we knew that before hand, they are *legitimate zeros*, they are biologically meaningful.